# Localizing iPhone app for Region

Tags: ios, localization, plist, nslocale

I've got an app that has all content regardless of language displaying content in English.  In the products section of the app product content is displayed based on a plist. Products available for purchased are based on location, not all products are available in every market.

In the settings of my simulator I've got my language set to **English** and my Region Format set to **Singapore**.

Above my loading of the plist which has been localized, I first do a log to check that I am in fact seeing SG (Singapore) as my region.

```
NSString *locale = [[NSLocale currentLocale] objectForKey: NSLocaleCountryCode];
NSLog(@"LOCALE: %@", locale);
if([locale isEqualToString:@"SG"]){
    NSLog(@"singapore do something?");
    productCategory = [[NSArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] 
                                    pathForResource:@"Products" ofType:@"plist"]];  
}
```

The current result is showing my log statement logging LOCALE: SG which is expected, however my Singapore specific content is not loading.

I have tried both cleaning the project, and deleting the app from the simulator.

This is how my plist files appear in my project navigator
[image: Products.plist image]

What am I doing incorrectly that is preventing my localized plist from being displayed?

Comment: My InfoPlist.strings file only says /* Localized versions of Info.plist keys */  -- It may be of note that my localization files for English and English-United Kingdom are working fine, however I noticed that those are differences in language settings not region settings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Localization (the process of loading translated resources from the relevant language folders in your application bundle) is based exclusively on the language setting. So pathForResource only cares about the language setting and ignores the region format setting.

The region format setting affects the conversion between strings and locale-dependent data types (in both directions: parsing input and formatting output). For example if you convert a NSDate to a string for display, depending on the region format setting you might get the month before the day (as in the US) or the opposite (as in the UK).

[NSLocale currentLocale] refers to the region format, so you were simply looking at the wrong thing in your debugging.

There is plenty more info on this here: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPInternational/BPInternational.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000171i

**Edit**
See the comments below, this appears to be more complex. It looks like Region does affect localisation when the language is set to a neutral language (e.g. "en" but not "en-US").

Comment: "Localization...is based exclusively on the language setting" Is that statement true? If I localize a string resource to "es" and "es-PY" files and set the language to es and the region to PY, my iPad app chooses the PY over the general language localization of es. If I set it the region to something else, like Peru, the app will correctly fall back to the language string of es.

Comment: es-PY means Spanish as spoken in Paraguay. You can be running an app with es-PY as language, and set the region format to something else. The language affects the localised strings you'll get (as you describe), but the region format won't (instead this affects how your read and write dates, numbers, monetary numbers).

Comment: I've tested this on iOS10 - if I have an es-PY and a general es localization in the bundle then change the iPad language setting to Spanish (general, non-region specific="es") and the region to es-PY (Espanol-Paraguay), it will pick up the es-PY region strings instead of the general es string, proving that the region DOES affect the strings (if you have that locale in the bundle). If I then switch the region to something else, like Peru, since I DON'T have that region string localization it falls back to the general es string from the bundle. See AppleBundleGuide->Search Order section

Answer (score 0):

I had once the same problem, somehow a non-localized file was found. What worked for me was to use:

```
[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Products" ofType:@"plist" inDirectory:nil]
```

This will always search for all localized files and return the correct one based on the users settings